# Contract class references member which is not part of the abstract class/interface being annotated

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Hi I'm Trying to make a simple code contract for a setter which states a DateTime Has to be at least fifteen years old.

If I do the validation in a member of the contract class the compiler yields

> Contract class 'TypeValidation.CodeContract.CitizenContract' references member 'TypeValidation.CodeContract.CitizenContract.BeGreaterThanFiveTeenYearsOld(System.DateTime)' which is not part of the abstract class/interface being annotated.

My code is:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(CitizenContract))]
public interface ICitizen
{
    int Age { get; set; }
    DateTime BirtDate { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(ICitizen))]
public class CitizenContract : ICitizen
{
    public int Age
    {
        get { return default(int); }
        set
        {

            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(value > 15, "Age must be sixteen or greater.");
        }
    }


    public DateTime BirtDate
    {
        get { return default(DateTime); }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld(value), "The birthdate has to be a minimum of sixteen years old");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return default(string); }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value), "Name Cant be null or empty.");
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(value.Length >= 3 && value.Length <= 50, "Name has to have between three and fifty.");
        }
    }

    bool MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld(DateTime dateToValidate)
    {

        if (dateToValidate == default(DateTime)) return false;

        DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (currentTime <= dateToValidate) return false;
        TimeSpan span = currentTime - dateToValidate;
        return ((zeroTime + span).Year - 1) >= 16;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it complains, can anyone explain why? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried "clean solution"?  It looks like you renamed one of your validation methods but it's being cached.

Comment: I think you are missing something - I cannot see BeGreaterThanFiveTeenYearsOld in your file even when the compiler complains abt this variable/prop

Comment: Yes I've tried to clean an recompile the project several times

Comment: Nikita, the member is "MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld". I'm sorry the error message is an older one, someone has edited know it's ok

Comment: Try making the validation method public:  `public bool MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld`

Comment: I've done it public but the same error "Contract class 'TypeValidation.CodeContract.CitizenContract' references member 'TypeValidation.CodeContract.CitizenContract.MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld(System.DateTime)' which is not part of the abstract class/interface being annotated."

Comment: Can you provide a repeatable, minimal version?  Start a new solution+project copy your code in and try again.  I tried your code as-is in both local visual studio and dotnetfiddle and there's no complaint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add new members, because the contracts are evaluated on arbitrary instances of `ICitizen`, not on instances of `CitizenContract`, and those  don't have that method. Because your method does not actually need the instance, you can make it `static`. This is not enough to silence the error, but you can move the method to another class. Also, the method should be `public` and `[Pure]`:

```
public static class CitizenContractHelpers {
    [Pure]
    public static bool MoreThanFifTeenYearsOld(DateTime dateToValidate) {
    …
    }
}
```

Also, the contract class should be `abstract`.

Read the manual at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf, there is everything you needed to know.

This example is not a good use of Code Contracts, which should be used to find programming bugs. Validity of your contract depends on the environment `DateTime.Now`, which the programmer usually does not control (the user can change time on his computer while using your application). So in this case a simple if-throw check in the implemenations would be better.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpfull